# maven-release-plugin with property activated profiles

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a project where most of profiles are activated automatically based on a combination of a file presence and a system property. For example:

```
        <profile>
        <id>when-releasing-java-generate-sources</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/main/java</exists>
            </file>
            <property>
                <name>build.release</name>
            </property>
```

Now I need to release and deploy this project's artifacts and I will use maven-release-plugin.

My problem is that my profiles are not being activated even if I'm passing -Dbuild.release in the command-line. 
Also I've tried to use -Darguments=-Dbuild.release, but could not see the plugins that are set in the profiles being executed.

So, there are any way to activate my project's profiles with maven-release-plugin ?

Comment: Can you show the definition of maven-release-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I was able to find where the issue was. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours digging into my issue I found the solution.

First thing that I discovered was that maven-release-plugin has an annoying limitation: it doesn't work when your project has an aggregator POM that is not the parent.

So the first thing that I had to solve was bring the parent POM up to the top of projects hierarchy and turn it the aggregator also.

Once that was done I needed to set the release-plugin up this way:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <arguments>-Dc8tech.build.release -Dc8tech.build.test.coverage ${arguments}</arguments>
        <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
        <releaseProfiles>when-releasing-ensure-requirements</releaseProfiles>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then I was able to release my project properly.